# Omission of the article in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if the highlighted part of the following sentence from `Fulton, Intersection Theory` is correct or if it is a pun?

> Omission of topics or references which should be included may be attributed to lack of space, as usual, but is more likely due to *incompetence of writer*.

Comment: It's a play on words - the article is dropped so that *incompetence of writer* parallels *lack of space*. Maybe not a pun exactly, but the same kind of thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the writer is making fun of themselves as they take responsibility for any errors in the article. It is not a pun but a self deprecating reference or description of themselves. I cannot see any pun for miles.

Comment: Oh, I always thought a pun was a joke on the meaning of a sentence, not on the sound. Seems like I need to reevaluate all 'no pun intended' jokes now... Thanks!

Comment: Puns can include many things. Often the similar sounds of words or other unintentional similarities. Remember; puns are bad but poetry is verse.